# I want to create new server farm in SharePoint 2013 it give validation error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have one SharePoint farm which is not working and now I run product configuration and want to create new server farm

it give blow error see image:

[image]

can anyone tell me how to resolve it

Comment: looks like problem with your IIS, do you already have the web site on the same Port 15108? is their any website you can see in IIS?

Comment: I give different ports but still the same error